# open view using html form in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am fairly new to codeigniter, or you can say new to MVC framewrork, i just want to load view 'landing', when user clicks on HTML form submit button, currently when i am using i.e what do i have to type in the action attribute to make it goto 'landing' view. ihave something like this

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right" action="<?php $this->load->view('landing')" ?> style="margin-right:20px; margin-top:4px;">
```

it either says object not found or you dont have permission

Comment: You can not load view directly in form action.You have to call a controller function and then load view within that controller function

Answer (score 1):

You have to submit form on a controller method which will load the new form

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('controllername/methodname');?>" method = "POST">
```

Now controller method

```
function methodname(){

      $this->load->view('landing');

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it wrong. The way explained by Raheel Shan is correct. You can't include a template in the form action attribute.

```
$this->load->view
```

includes (loads) the template file, it does not provide the url to the template. Think of it like php include , include_one or required and required_once statements.

Kindly read the codeigniter documentation as it is very easy.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Thank you